# AD testing tool

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

We use sharepoint, and in SP we have a people picker which searches on samaccountname but also on name.  On dev it works fine, but on prod it returns sometimes duplicated results.

I wonder if there is an easy application there which I can make queries against the AD and see the results.   (Maybe the duplicated users are really in different domains in one ad forest or something.

I found this, but it doesnt have a working example in c#
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973834.aspx

Comment: You should use `ldapsearch`. It is the standard command line tool for querying a directory server. `ldapsearch` is distributed with directory server software and is widely available. For more information, see ["Using ldapsearch"](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/mastering-ldapsearch/). This tool should be used to verify parameters and assumptions before any other code is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got two snippets for this :

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.DirectoryServices;

// Authentication
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDn))
{
   // validate the credentials
   bIsValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(sUsr, sPassword);
}

//List users
DirectorySearcher adsSearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
adsSearcher.Filter = string.Format(Parameters.ActiveDirectoryFilter, "*");
try
{
   foreach (SearchResult sr in adsSearcher.FindAll())
   {
       string sUsrName = sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["UserPrincipalName"].Value as string;
       Console.WriteLine(string.Format("User : {0}", sUsrName));
   }
}
```

Of course, it needs two references (System.DirectoryServices and System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement).